# How to retrieve data in sorted manner

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch data from firebase real time database in Ascending order.

```
BirthdayPersons        //This is main node
-Lfk hfkfks   //This is sun node
dob: "01/10/2019"
name: "Random Name"
uid: "randomstring"
rem: 5   //Sort according to this

-Lafkjhf fksjfj
dob: "01/10/2019"
name: "Random Name"
uid: "randomstring"
rem: 5
```

I have Json tree of this format and I want the data in ascending order according to `remaining`

This is my database model class

```
data class Databasemodel(val uid:String, val name:String, val dob:String,val rem:Int) {

constructor():this("",",","",0)
}
```

Comment: This is not sufficient, please post database structure with at least one full content so that we can understand the structure. Thanks

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman ok I have edited, is that enough

Comment: Have you seen the documentation for [how to sort data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) using `orderByChild`?  What have you tried so far and what specific API are you using (e.g. Android, Web, Admin, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstsnce().getReference("BirthdayPersons").orderByChild("rem")
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
        @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
            // implement logic here
        } 
        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException()); 
        }  
});
```

Comment: How to control ascending or descending

Comment: Unfortunately firebase doesn't allow returning by descending order. You can reverse the list in client side after receiving